# Create overview page of pages with specific order

Tags: sorting, bolt-cms

I use Bolt for a local radio station. We've created the content type 'Broadcasts'. When I create an overview page I can see all pages in that section. They are sorted by the date they where created in the system. But I want some other sorting. The broadcasts are on several days of the week and have their own broadcast times. How can I sort all these pages by day and time on that day? Is there a simple way to do this automatically? So when I add a new broadcast page, that it is listed on the overview page also under the right week day and time. I'm thinking about adding more input fields to collect the info to sort (week day and time). Can I sort with this variables?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have two fields in your contenttype, for the 'day' and 'time'. On the page, it's easiest to add an extra loop, iterating over the programs for each day. Something like this:

```
{% set days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'] %} 
{% for day in days %} 

  {% setcontent broadcasts = "broadcasts" where { 'day': day } orderby 'time' %}
  <h2>Program for {{ day }}</h2>
  {% for broadcast in broadcasts %}
    ...
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to select the day using a checkbox? I couldn't find this as an field option in the documentation... Or should I do this with a 'selectfield'?